# curl Failed to import cert file client.crt on command prompt and Powershell works fine on gitbash

Tags: powershell, curl

I am using Windows...

When I run the following curl command through gitbash it works fine:

```
curl --cacert ca.crt --key client.key --cert client.crt "https://myurl"
```

However, if I try to run the same command in command prompt or Powershell, I get this error:

```
curl: (58) schannel: Failed to import cert file client.crt, last error is 0x80092002
```

What do I need to do to get the command working in Command Prompt or Powershell?

Comment: i never use `curl.exe`, so this is just a WAG ... have you compared the versions? the one that comes with win10 is `7.79.1` and the one that works for you may be a different version with different abilities/parameters.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey spot on. The Windows version of Curl 7.79.1 is broken for want of a better description. Older versions work fine. I'm using 7.59.0 and having great success with it.

Answer (score 15):

Windows version of curl.exe is not configured to work with openssl but git's is.

So to make sure whenever I typed 'curl' into a command prompt, it was using git's version of curl I added the path to git's curl (C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin) in system environment variables and moved it right to the top…so it find’s git’s curl before it finds window’s curl.

After then restarted the command prompt it resolved the issue.

Comment: I applied this approach with slight adjustments and it works perfectly. The only thing which different for me is that I used chocolatey to install curl and then I moved `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin` to the top of my env variables as you suggested. I think it might be beneficial in case you use other packages from chocolatey in your daily work and you'd like to have full control over them.

Comment: This answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, with both windows curl and mingw(git) both where version 8.4.0
I downloaded curl 8.6.0 from here https://curl.se/windows/ and it soved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You are providing your client certificate in the wrong format. `curl` requires the certificate in the PEM format ([source](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl)):

> ```
> -E/--cert <certificate[:password]>
>      (SSL) Tells curl to use the specified certificate file when getting a file with 
>      HTTPS or FTPS. The certificate must be in PEM format. If the optional password 
>      isn't specified, it will be queried for on the terminal. Note that this option 
>      assumes a "certificate" file that is the private key and the private 
>      certificate concatenated! See --cert and --key to specify them independently.
>
>      If curl is built against the NSS SSL library then this option can tell curl the 
>      nickname of the certificate to use within the NSS database defined by the 
>      environment variable SSL_DIR (or by default /etc/pki/nssdb). If the NSS PEM 
>      PKCS#11 module (libnsspem.so) is available then PEM files may be loaded. If you 
>      want to use a file from the current directory, please precede it with "./" 
>      prefix, in order to avoid confusion with a nickname.
>
>      If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.
> ```

Your certificate might be in the DER format or contain a whole certificate chain instead of your single client certificate.

Comment: The file IS in PEM format (text). I have also converted the file to a .pem extension but still get the same problem (curl: (58) schannel: Failed to import cert file client.pem, last error is 0x80092002). Also it works fine in gitbash - just not in cmd or powershell

Comment: So it looks like windows in built curl isn't configured to work with openSSL This is the git version details that works: curl 7.70.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.70.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1g (Schannel) zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.3.0 libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.40.0. This is the windows curl version details that doesn't work: curl 7.79.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.79.1 Schannel

Answer (score 0):

On our Windows 2019 server we have two curl.exe.
By default, the version 7.83.1 was summoned.
The issue was solved by using the version 7.54.1 and adding the full path to access it.

Answer (score -1):

in the manpage of curl, it is described that on Windows, it uses schannel provider by default (which itself uses the windows store). I am on the same errand now :-) trying to find a way to pass the certs from the command line and from local files.

Perhaps try importing the certs into the Windows store.